# how to handle session in mutliple tabs in a browser in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, web

I am  using asp.net C# and am unable to manage sessions per multiple tabs. The scenario for my website is, USER logs in, then Selects a job and then Apply for that job, and when user applies, an entry is done in database against that request. It will store, selected job ID, and Email id of that user.

By problem which i am facing is, if i open login page in a browser in 2 different tabs. the entry data gets messed up. for example, 
USER A selected job 1, and user B selected job 2, when i press apply button from user B, his selected job, and user A's email id are entered in database.

I tried to solve this problem by checking if the session object is NULL/empty, only then a new session should be created. else, the other user should get error that he cant login. but my code doesn't work every time. It gives me result sometimes, and sometimes it just simply doesn't run. here is my code:

```
protected void session_create(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Session[s]))
    {
        Session[s] = s;
        test.Text = "Welcome user,  " + (string)(Session[s]);
    }
    else
    {
        test.Text = "You are Already logged in";
    }
}
```

and then i call this method on_submit button:

```
session_create("email");
```

because i m storing only email variable, i am passing email parameter.

where,

```
string email = emailtextbox.Text;
```

So, anybody has any idea how can i resolve this issue? a user shouldn't be allowed to login in multiple tabs from a same browser. please help.

Comment: I have solved this issue by adding this paramenter in web.config file.
$'<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseUri"></sessionState></system.web>
but i dont know if its such a good solution. if anybody has any better ideas plz lemme know.

Comment: Do you use the builtin Membershipsystem for user handling?

Comment: Is this a realistic scenario? Two different users logging in using different tabs in the same browser?

Comment: a user can make two ids too. What if he makes two ids and tries to login at the same time? and also malicious users would try to wreck my system.

Comment: @MalcolmFrexner no i didnt use tht. i am kindda new to c#. but thanx for the idea.i have started exploring it.

Comment: check out HttpContext.Context.Session https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.session?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using InProc session state, in your WEB.CONFIG.

View this link for more information : http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/364203/Stop-Sharing-Session-State-between-Multiple-Tabs-o

Comment: lol. didnt u read my solution? i already did tht, i was hoping for a better suggestion.